# Modified files by Google Chrome

Tags: linux, files, chrome, google

Hello how can I obtain the modified files by Google Chrome. For example, if one web application accesses and modifies the one local file in the user's directory how can I find out?

Comment: Do you mean the google docs or like cache and setting for for the actual chrome browser?

Comment: No I am talking about local user files. For example, web applications can use local file system API to access user's local files if such event is happened how can I obtain whether the web application accessed the user's local files?

Comment: [Auditing](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) may help. The problem is finding out whether a file write was initiated by the browser. You can filter audit records by PID, but if the browser uses a new process to update files, it's difficult.

Comment: You could use `inotifywait` as well - plenty of examples on the net